# Why does Kentico CMS remove i tags

Tags: html, tags, kentico

I am doing a web page for work and their site uses the Kentico CMS. I prefer writing in html in sublime and copying it into the source. I have just noticed when I do this any `i` tags are automatically removed. I have some floating buttons which allow the user to click to go back to the top of the page with this,

```
<a href="#URTI" class="float">
   <i class="fa fa-arrow-up my-float"></i>
 </a>
```

when I copy this in and save the whole piece of code disappears... If I just write,

```
<a href="#URTI" class="float"></a>
```

I get the circle (styled in the float class) and it will take the user back to the top when clicked.

Is there some odd reason why `i` tags are being removed?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add empty HTML tags, such as i tags.
Empty tags are removed by the editor when the source HTML is saved. A workaround is to add a   character entity (a non-breaking space) between the tags.